# Android Jet Pack Navigation, setupWithNavController() recreating fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, navigation, fragment

I have a problem with my navigation view using jetpack's BottomNavBar

so here's how my flow works.

I have 4 views and every one of them have redirections like when I'm in last selection of the navbar I have a `fragment A` -> `fragment B` and when I go back to the first selection of the navbar and when I go back to the 4th one its one the `fragment A` again. I believe it is because fragments are recreating using the `setupWithNavController()` if it so does jetpack have a workaround for that?

here is my code for some reference.

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@+id/splashFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/selectionFragment"
        android:name="whitecloak.com.allibuy.app.selection.SelectionFragment"
        android:label="fragment_selection"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_selection" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/toLogin"
            app:destination="@id/loginFragment"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/nav_graph" 
            app:popUpToInclusive="true/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
       android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
       android:name="whitecloak.com.allibuy.app.splash.SplashFragment"
        android:label="fragment_splash"
        tools:layout="@layout/splash_fragment"
        >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/toMain"
            app:destination="@id/mainFragment"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/nav_graph"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
    </fragment>
```

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/home"
    android:title="@string/home"
    app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/tabCart"
    android:icon="@drawable/cart"
    android:title="@string/cart"
    app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/tabNotif"
    android:icon="@drawable/notification"
    android:title="@string/notification"
    app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/selectionFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/user"
    android:title="@string/account"
    app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph" />
```

```
bottomNav.setupWithNavController(findNavController(R.id.nav_main))
```

I just included the XML for the 1st and last tab. Thank you so much.

### EDIT

```
class MainNavigation : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainNavigationViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)[MainNavigationViewModel::class.java]

        bottomNav.setupWithNavController(findNavController(R.id.nav_main))
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe you should included some Kotlin to go along to help us understand the context and the code being done. I, for example, would like to see where is `bottomNav.setupWithNavController` called.

Comment: @shkschneider - I updated the code and there it is. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not related to the setup of your BottomNav. It's rather the explicit behavior in the implementation made for Android. I'll quote and explain:

> Behavior
> On Android: the app navigates to a destination’s **top-level screen**. Any prior user interactions and temporary screen states are reset, such as scroll position, tab selection, and in-line search.

From https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html#behavior

This means that when you click an item on the BottomNav, it should always go back to the first fragment on this flow's stack.

---

If I'm not being clear, here is a pseudo-representation:

> BottomNavItem#1 > Fragment1A > Fragment1B
>
> BottomNavItem#2 > Fragment2A > Fragment2B

If you tap on `BottomNavItem#1`, it loads `Fragment1A`. Then imagine using a button it shows `Fragment1B`. If you now click on `BottomNavItem#2`, you'll see `Fragment2A`. Now, if you click back on `BottomNavItem#1`, it will show `Fragment1A` (*not* the `Fragment1B` that you saw last), because it's the root of that stack/flow.

Comment: Is there something you can recommend that I be doing for workaround or something that I would change?

Comment: It is certainly highly discouraged with the standard widget, and I never implemented such thing (be cautious about the 'back' behavior) so sadly `no`, I don't know how one would customize this. I just explained why it happened. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for bringing me this info sir!

Comment: You are very welcome. If you find something useful, answer your own question, it might help others ;)